# Trouble loading a picture using plyer module in python

Tags: python-3.x

I was writing a Python program which uses the plyer module. The program will show me a notification whenever I run it. I am running into this problem: Exception: Could not load icon D:\python.jpeg. I have entered the correct path to the file python.jpeg. I have tried to use pictures of different resolutions (256 x 256, 96 x 96, 48 x 48) thinking the icon should have a lower resolution but to no avail. What is causing this error and how can I solve it? Thanks in advance!

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify(title="This is a random notification", message = "What's Up?", timeout = 5, app_icon = "D:\\python.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the plyer docs (https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#plyer.facades.Notification)

> When called on Windows, app_icon has to be a path to a file in .ICO format.